# Interger representing a Array value is increasing within a for loop when trying to assign characters to a 2D Character array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, char, ifstream

in my program I am attempting to input characters from a .txt file and assign them to a 2D Char array to form a Maze. The expected outcome of this code is:

```
xxxxxxx
xA...Bx
xxxxxxx
```

However I am instead warned that Column is greater than size (defined as 30) when I believe it should be 0 at the start of every loop. No matter what Column is equal to Size and im not sure why. I've included the code below. I am beginner programmer so if you have any advice could you please make it as simple as possible.
Many thanks,
Ben

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <vector>
//Maze Size
#define SIZE 30
using namespace std;

void readMaze(string fileName);

void inputMaze();

int main()
{
    inputMaze();   
}

void readMaze(string fileName)
{
    int rows;
    int columns = 0;
    //vector<vector<char>> maze;    
    char maze[SIZE][SIZE];
    ifstream input(fileName);
    char data;
    while (input.get(data))   //While loop used to store each individual data to the string.
    {

        for (int rows = 0; rows < 20; rows++)
        {
            columns = 0;
            while (data != '\n')
            {
                if (rows > SIZE)
                {
                    cout << "ROWS GREATER THAN SIZE";
                    break;
                }
                else if (columns > SIZE)
                {
                    cout << "COLUMNS GREATER THAN SIZE";
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    maze[rows][columns] = data;
                    columns++;
                    data = input.get();
                }
            }
                data = input.get();
            }
        }
        cout << "The Maze being solved is: " << endl;
        cout << maze << endl;
        input.close();
}


void inputMaze()
{
    string userinput;
    cout << "Plese input a .txt file name" << endl;
    cin >> userinput; //User inputs the name of a .txt file --> goes to readMaze()
    readMaze(userinput);
}
```

Comment: What does stepping through the code in the debugger tell you?

Comment: I suggest that you make it `std::vector<std::vector<char>> maze;` instead to not need to have a fixed size limit of 30.

Comment: @KenWhite stepping through doesn't actually produce any output in the debug console. For some reason nothing happens?

Comment: @TedLyngmo So i've altered it to `vector<vector<char>> maze;` but I now have a syntax error when trying to output Maze. `no operator "<<" matches these operands`

Comment: ***doesn't actually produce any output in the debug console*** Even in this case you should be able to see what is going on. Look at the variables at each step you take in the debugger. Examine the flow.

Comment: Set a watchpoint on the `columns` variable, and then step through the code line by line to inspect what's happening with that variable within the execution of your code. It has nothing to do with the debug console.

Comment: @KenWhite Through your advice, columns will count up to 7 with the loop before resetting to 0. (Which is intended) However after 2 loops it surpasses 7 and continues on until it eventually reaches size and resets to 0.

Comment: This question's shown code does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre]. This means it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You should [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Apoligies, I've included the rest of the code now. It should now be reproducable.

Comment: If stepping through the code doesn't reveal that `columns` is > 30, then you can't be getting the warning that you say you're getting. Can you explain that?

Comment: @KenWhite my bad. I've just ran through it again and it reaches 31 before resetting to 0 and finally setting rows++. This occurs from rows = 2 onwards. The intended output only has 3 rows so I need to find a way for it to stop looping once its the end of file with using input.eof()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rows` is used uninitialized in `readMaze` so the program has undefined behavior. Also, `cout << maze << endl;` makes the program have undefined behavior by reading out of bounds.

Consider making `maze` a `std::vector<std::vector<char>>` or even a `std::vector<std::string>` to make it simpler.

Example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> readMaze(std::istream& input) {
    std::vector<std::string> maze;
    std::string line;

    while(std::getline(input, line)) { // read a complete line at a time
        maze.push_back(line);          // and save it in the vector 
    }

    return maze;
}

void inputMaze() {
    std::string userinput;
    std::cout << "Plese input a .txt file name\n";

    if(std::cin >> userinput) {
        std::ifstream is(userinput);
        if(is) {
            auto maze = readMaze(is);

            std::cout << "The Maze being solved is:\n";
            std::copy(maze.begin(), maze.end(),
                      std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
        }
        // the file will be closed automatically when "is" goes out of scope
    }
}

int main() {
    inputMaze();   
}
```